# mongodb: What minimum roles are required to list available databases?

Tags: mongodb

So, I have a user for mongo db with the following roles:

```
% mongo --username userw --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --host host
...
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show users
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525d880dcd6e5e57f9431e16"),
    "user" : "userw",
    "pwd" : "****************",
    "roles" : [
        "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "listDatabases"
    ]
}
```

The user can read and write successfully to any database, but if I do:

```
> show dbs
Thu Oct 17 08:46:27.523 listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:46
```

I seem to be missing a role that lets me list databases. Which role do I need? (clusterAdmin fixes this, but seems overkill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/), the user must be granted the `clusterAdmin` role for the `listDatabases` privilege